# VBA Word, Remove Specific Highlighting Color "Red" get stuck some times at infinite loop

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to delete the red highlighting color from the MS Word document.

Explanation:
I made a module in MS Word documents that search/find any text highlighting with red color - a text marked with red from the tool shown in the image below. The following code is either working fine or make the MS Word stop responding. I'm not sure why it gets crashing, but I guess due to the loop that I am using. I wish there is something like: .Replacement.HighlightColorIndex = wdred ; and then .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll ; instead of the loop.

[image]

The VBA code that I wrote:

```
Sub RemoveSpecificHighlightingColor()
'
' Remove Specific Highlighting Color Macro
' This Macro go through the document and search for any Red color highlighting word and remove it
' colors code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdcolorindex
'
    Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, 1 'Start at the top of the document
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Highlight = True
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop 'stop at the end of the document
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        Do While (.Execute(Forward:=True) = True) = True
            DoEvents 'keeps Word responsive
            If Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed Then
               Selection.Range.Delete
            End If
        Loop
        MsgBox "Done!" ' just for testing
    End With
End Sub
```

Some explanation about the code:

- I noticed if I select at the middle of the document then run the code, the code start from the mouse selection not from the top. This is why I mentioned the first statement.
- Some of the code I got from the record marco feature and from help online. The record marco detect all highlighting color not specific color.
- I used Selection.Find so I selected .Wrap = wdFindStop
- There is no difference if I keep or remove Format, MatchCase, MatchWholeWord, MatchWildcards, MatchSoundsLike, and MatchAllWordForms.
- The main issue is the While loop or any loop that I am using. The one shown in the code check for all highlighting colors and if the color is red, then remove it, otherwise check for another.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to trace the issue. What I noticed is, in some documents only (mixed of .doc and .docx file type), once I run the code, it goes through the document pages and finds and deletes the red highlighting color, that once all are replaced, the MS Word stuck. Once the MS Word got stuck, the cursor is changing rapidly, as if the screen has to be redrawn, and after a few seconds the program stops responding, and even if I wait for a while it will be stuck until I force to close the MS Word. This happened with or without red highlighting color in the document.

Explanation of the code:

- The code runs each page alone by making the code start from the first page and count the number of pages. Then go through each page and select the text.
- Apply the filtering code and deleting for the specific selection only, then check for a new page.
- I treated the pause/stuck as a bouncing button without a pull-up or pull-down resistor i.e., once the physical button is pressed it fluctuate before it reaches a steady state.
- Iteration...

The final code that I used, and It's now working for all documents is shown below:

```
Sub RemoveSpecificHighlightingColor()
'
' Remove Specific Highlighting Color Macro
' This Macro go through the document and search for any Red color highlighting word and remove it
' colors code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdcolorindex
'
    Dim NumberOfAllPages As Integer
    ' Dim LastPageNumber As Integer
    Dim PageNumber As Integer
    Dim TempCounter As Integer
    Dim TemoEnd As Long
    
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    PageNumber = 1 'Starting page
    NumberOfAllPages = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages.Count
   ' LastPageNumber = 3 'Last page to reach - for testing
    Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, PageNumber 'GoTo Page PageNumber
    
   ' Debug.Print "Start"
    While PageNumber - 1 < NumberOfAllPages 'LastPageNumber
        DoEvents 'keeps document responsive
        Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, PageNumber 'GoTo Page PageNumber
        Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Select 'Select all the text in the page
        
        With Selection.Find
            .Highlight = True
            .Text = ""
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            Do While (.Execute(Forward:=True) = True) = True
                DoEvents 'keeps document responsive

                If Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed Then Selection.Range.Delete
                
                ' If the process is stuck at the same location for while then (50 times) it mean the page is full check from Red Highlighting Color
                If ActiveWindow.Selection.End = TemoEnd Then
                    TempCounter = TempCounter + 1
                End If
                If TempCounter > 50 Then Exit Do
                
              '  Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Range.End
              '  Debug.Print ActiveWindow.Selection.End
                
                TemoEnd = ActiveWindow.Selection.End
            Loop
        End With
        TempCounter = 0 ' reset counter
       ' Debug.Print PageNumber
        PageNumber = PageNumber + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The big problem with your code is that you are using the `Selection` object. When you select things in your code the screen has to be redrawn with each change of selection. As `Selection.Find` selects every match it finds that is a lot of redrawing.

In this instance you can avoid using `Selection` by using a `Range` object instead (`ActiveDocument.Content` is a range). When you use `.Find` with a range the range is redefined each time a match is found, enabling you to change the properties of that range.

```
Sub RemoveSpecificHighlightingColor()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   With ActiveDocument.Content
      With .Find
         .ClearFormatting
         .Replacement.ClearFormatting
         .Highlight = True
         .Text = ""
         .Replacement.Text = ""
         .Forward = True
         .Wrap = wdFindStop 'stop at the end of the document
         .Format = True
         .MatchCase = False
         .MatchWholeWord = False
         .MatchWildcards = False
         .MatchSoundsLike = False
         .MatchAllWordForms = False
      End With
      Do While .Find.Execute = True
         If .HighlightColorIndex = wdRed Then .Delete
      Loop
   End With
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Still the same issue, for some documents it's working fine and for other documents it's crashing the MS Word. The cursor is changing rapidly, as if the screen has to be redrawn even after `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. Because this reason I forced to close the document. The document is 7 pages long as .docx file type (same like other documents). The last two document that lead to crashes, one have no highlight color at all, while the other one have multiple different highlight color and none is red.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Format = True
    .Forward = True
    .Highlight = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    If .HighlightColorIndex = wdRed Then .Delete
    'The next If ... End If block is needed if the highlighted content could be in a table
    If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
      If .End = .Cells(1).Range.End - 1 Then
        .End = .Cells(1).Range.End
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        If .Information(wdAtEndOfRowMarker) = True Then
          .End = .End + 1
        End If
      End If
    End If
    'The next line is  needed if the highlighted content could include the final paragraph break
    If .End = ActiveDocument.Range.End Then Exit Do
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Do note that there's a bug in Word's Find which means it won't find anything if the document consists of a single highlighted paragraph. Additionally, I haven't included code to test whether a found range spans some text as well as part of a field or spans two or more highlight colours. Consequently, neither condition will be processed.

Comment: More efficient code, but still I am having the same problem. Almost all the documents it's working fine except for few documents it's crashing the MS Word once I run the macro. Now, I'm trying to inspect the problem, any thoughts?

Comment: I am unable to replicate the problem. Unless you can identify the document feature(s) concerned and what you mean by 'crash', all you leave anyone with is a guessing game.

Comment: I managed to fix it, the code is answered in this page by me with explanation. I have basic knowledge about coding VBA, so I would appreciate if you can help me improve it and makes it faster.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you where your error is, but here's a working code

```
Sub UNHIGHCOLOR()
'HOW MANY HIGHLIGHT REGIONS ARE - store to AAAM
Selection.HomeKey wdStory
'HIG_COUNT Macro
'CTRL-FN-SHIFT TO BREAK
START:
'Selection.HomeKey wdStory
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Highlight = True
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute
If .Found Then
'MsgBox "found"
If Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed Then
'MsgBox "RED"
'Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = 0
End If
AAAM = AAAM + 1
GoTo START
Else
'MsgBox "not found"
'MsgBox AAAM & " HIGH REGIONS"
End If
End With
Selection.HomeKey wdStory
'*********************************************************
'FOR AAAM REGIONS CHANGE HIGHLIGHT RED COLORS TO NO COLOR
For X = 1 To AAAM + 1
'UNHIGHCOLOR_RED_NEXT
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Highlight = True
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute
    End With
    If Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed Then
    'MsgBox "RED"
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = 0 'NO COLOR
    End If
    Selection.Collapse (wdCollapseEnd) 'TO FIND NEXT
    Next
End Sub
```